# Increase the max rendering time in QGIS to avoid network timeout error in WFS

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I have QGIS(3.28.15) running on my local(windows) and a WFS 2.0.0 connection established to GeoServer(2.23.2) hosted on Linux VM. The layer i am trying to load into QGIS from GeoServer is quite big in size (around 2GB i.e inclusive of .shp and all other supporting files, feature count 100000+).

I am getting network time out error and not able to load the layer into QGIS.

WFS log- Attributes are not able to download or are partially downloaded.

I suspect that the issue is due to the size and either the GeoServer or QGIS is not able to complete the request within max request time and throwing Network timeout error.

I will be dealing with large files often in future and would like a robust solution for loading big files into QGIS also edit commit changes.

Note-

1. I have tried with two big files and am having the same error.
2. I have tried the same with tomcat9 and GeoServer setup on local and still same issue.
3. I have tried to drag and drop the file from my local files to QGIS and it is loading.
4. I have no pluggins installed.
5. Everything is on default settings.

Comment: Is this accessing the local network or internet. There are too many variables to give you an accurate answer. try adding some ping\tracert times to your question.